# Evenly distributed random strings in Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to generate random strings (or arrays) of 1's and 0's. Then I classify them according to quantity (count) of 1's.  I want the generated strings to be evenly distributed among the possible counts.

But the following code gives me a normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np

for i in range(num_examples):
    seq = np.random.randint(2, size=(seq_length)).astype('float32')
    sequences[i] = seq

target_classes = []
for input in sequences: 
    target = (input == 1).sum()
    target_classes.append(target)
```

The histogram of counts is:

[image]

A NumPy solution would be awesome. Or do I need regular expressions or something else?

Comment: "So I want the generated strings to be evenly distributed in these classes" - why do you expect them to be evenly distributed *in these classes*? That's like expecting 0 heads to be as likely as 50 heads in a sequence of 100 coin flips.

Comment: This seems more of a mathematical or statistical problem. Once you know the math that produces the distribution you want, converting it to Python should be straightforward.

Comment: Strings? I don't see what you mean...

Comment: OP didn't say he *expects* them to be evenly distributed, but that he *wants* them evenly distributed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga string or array, not a problem. I can convert one to another.

Comment: What you have is the result of the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.0wikipedia.org/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvQ2VudHJhbF9saW1pdF90aGVvcmVt) You have independent (uniform) random variables and their sum follows a normal distribution centered around `n*p`.

Comment: @Prune exactly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Prune already noted this is essentially a 2-step process. First you need to create an uniform distribution of the "number of ones" (for example with [`np.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)), then you need to set that many "seq" elements to one (for example using [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)).

One possibility would be:

```
import numpy as np

NUM_EXAMPLES = 10000
SEQ_LENGTH = 10

sequences = np.zeros((NUM_EXAMPLES, SEQ_LENGTH), dtype=np.int8)
# How many number of ones in each sequence
number_of_1s = np.random.randint(0, SEQ_LENGTH+1, size=NUM_EXAMPLES)

indices = np.arange(SEQ_LENGTH)
for idx, num_ones in enumerate(number_of_1s.tolist()):
    # Set "num_ones" elements to 1 using "choice" without replace.
    sequences[idx][np.random.choice(indices, num_ones, replace=False)] = 1
```

Using a histogram shows that it seems to be quite evenly distributed:

```
plt.hist(np.sum(sequences==1, axis=1), bins=np.arange(SEQ_LENGTH+2)-0.5, histtype='step')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want equal distribution of the quantity of 1's, then I think you'll find it easiest to *first* generate the quantity, and *then* to randomly distribute that many 1's through the binary representation.  This is a two-step process, almost by necessity.

With that hint, can you do the coding on your own?

Comment: No, one **random** call to get the quantity, then something to distribute that many 1`s in a string of 0`s.  I don't see a role for regex in this.

Comment: I think I don't even need the random call. Just an integer array from 0 to (num_of_seq / len_of_seq). I will try to implement "something" part. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ... if you want to guarantee equal distribution, yes -- you do *not* need the first *random* call.  I was thinking of a *uniform random* distribution.